# external audio tracks not streaming via hls.js and m3u8

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, html5-video, m3u8, hls.js

I have an mp4 video file that I've converted to `.ts` file with ffmpeg for streaming via `m3u8`. along with that mp4 I also have multiple audio files as `.wav` that are the alternate audio files for the video. I have added them to a main `m3u8` file like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=850000,RESOLUTION=640x360,AUDIO="bipbop_audio"
index0.m3u8

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="bipbop_audio",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="BipBop Audio 1",
 AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="bipbop_audio",LANGUAGE="nr",NAME="BipBop Audio 2",
 AUTOSELECT=NO,DEFAULT=NO,URI="audio1.m3u8"
```

when I go to play this using hls.js in the browser the video file's `m3u8` is downloaded (index0.m3u8) and the video plays, but the audio file's `m3u8` files are not downloaded by the browser and the audio does not play. I can actually see the alternate audio info in the hls.js object instance that is in the main `m3u8` file when I console log it, but making hls.js switch to it does not make it download nor play.

So far I've tried:

1. converting the audio to `.mp3` via ffmpeg
2. converting the audio to `.ts` via ffmpeg

here is what the `.ts` version of the audio file looks like as an `m3u8`

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2914
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:2913.661333,
abc0.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I'm pretty new to ffmpeg and hls.js, but is there some specific way I need to make ffmpeg generate the `m3u8` files for both the audio and video to make them work together?
so far I don't see any errors in the browser relating to the main `m3u8` or hls.js.